# validate HTTP requests with header "origin"

Tags: php, http, ssl

1. I have a REST API in **https://domain1.com**
2. I want to accept requests only from **https://domain2.com**

Question, Can I rely on the "origin" header to accept request only from **https://domain2.com**?

**Note that Both websites are secured with SSL**

It would be something like this:

```
$headers = getallheaders();
if($headers['origin'] != 'https://domain2.com'){
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Define "rely on". It'd help, but any competent attacker could easily bypass this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Relying on the Origin header would be similar to relying on a Cookie.  A well-behaved client (such as a browser) will send it with the correct value.  An attacker would simply spoof it to whatever value they need to get your service to work.

You can use it as a way to prevent someone from using your API on their site directly from the browser.  You cannot use it to prevent someone from using your API via a proxy or accessing it directly to download data.